# replace string if it satisfies the condition pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, string, dataframe, rename

I have the following code and want to replace the country name if there is paranthesis in string or number and we have to remove it
e.g.
'Bolivia (Plurinational State of)' should be 'Bolivia',
'Switzerland17' should be 'Switzerland'.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile
pd.set_option('display.max_columns',None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows',None)

df=pd.read_excel('Energy Indicators.xls',skiprows=17, skipfooter=265-(227))
df.drop(df.columns[[0,1]], axis=1, inplace=True)
df.columns=['Country', 'Energy Supply', 'Energy Supply per Capita', '% Renewable']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `pd.DataFrame.str.replace`

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Country':['Bolivia (Plurinational State of)','Switzerland17'],'value':[1,2]})
df
#   Country                           value
#0  Bolivia (Plurinational State of)    1
#1  Switzerland17                       2

df.Country=df.Country.str.replace('\(.*\)|(\d+)','')
df
#   Country                           value
#0  Bolivia                             1
#1  Switzerland                         2
```

Comment: actually I want to replace all string containing brackets and numbers

Comment: What's the problem with the answer? when it doesn't work? @vedantaher

Comment: your answer specifies only about Bolivia (Plurinational State of... and Switzerland17 no? I am looking for a generalise code applicable for all str containing brackets and number

Comment: Sure, because they are the only elements in Country column.  Did you try it with your original dataframe? Also, you didn't answer my question... when does it fail?...@vedantaher It would be great if you would posted a sample data of your dataframe to work with and also the expected output.

Comment: df.Country=df.Country.str.replace('\(.*\)|(\d+)','') this code worked sorry for inconvininace can you explained it  a little I'm new in learning pandas

Comment: Sure, no worries. Be careful, it's `df.Country.str.replace('\(.*\)|(\d+)','')`, not `df.Country.str.replace('(.*)|(\d+)','')` . Also if it was helpful, upvoting the answer too. Thanks :)

Comment: @vedantaher A little explanation:  `\(.*\)` means all the substrings that are between brackets: `\( \)` the brackets, `.*` any number of characters, 
`|` bitwise or,  
`(\d+)` means a substring that contains digits.